# Merging large number of csv file into one csv file in row wise manner using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have large number of csv file(Japan.csv, Afghanistan.csv, Indonesia.csv.....) in which "Year is common in all csv files" and I want to store column like

> [**Year**  **Japan**  **Afghanistan**  **Indonesia** ......  ]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use Year as a shared index across all dataframes? Have you considered merging the DFs in an approach like:

```
df1.merge(df2, on = 'Year').set_index('Year')
```

Comment: brother I have lots of CSV file and the method you are saying is for merging 2 csv file only at time.

Comment: Use a for loop!